# How run this SQL in foreach Array to get unique Query

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have an Array,

```
$array = array("rating_battery", "rating_display", "rating_design");
```

Array output;

```
Array
(
    [0] => rating_battery
    [1] => rating_display
    [2] => rating_design
)
```

I have SQL Query,

```
$query = "SELECT ID, meta_value, meta_key
FROM table_name
WHERE meta_key = $value"
```

I use `foreach`;

```
foreach ( $array as $value ) {
    $query = "SELECT ID, meta_value, meta_key
    FROM table_name
    WHERE meta_key = $value"
}
```

How to get unique **`$query`** like this with **`foreach`**.

```
1. $query_rating_battery with meta_key = 'rating_battery'
2. $query_rating_display with meta_key = 'rating_display'
3. $query_rating_design with meta_key = 'rating_design'
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Why would you need that? How about using `WHERE meta_key IN implode(',', $value)` ?

Comment: why you are using foreach ??

Comment: @DainisAbols, how to get unique <pre>$query</pre>: such as <pre>$query_1</pre>, ect.

Comment: You can set `$query` as array `$query[]` and then you would get $query[0], $query[1] etc , but again, WHY do you need this? It is never wise to do multiple queries. Especially, if they are almost the same.

Comment: I explained, the value from array is user added. So, if create muliple query manualy, such as: $query_rating_display, $query_n. Is not autmaticly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use `WHERE IN`:

```
SELECT ID, meta_value, meta_key
FROM table_name
WHERE meta_key IN implode(',', $value)
```

Comment: Thanks. But, how to get unique $query? I need separate per query, not IN. Because IN get all data, not create unique $query

Comment: Fetch all of the data in 1 query and then filter it with php. Always try to make as less DB calls as possible.